# MusicGeneration VAE Model: ELBO=NONE

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, artificial-intelligence, autoencoder

I'm training a VAE model for generating music. When I tried to train this model and the program ran to the 9th epoch, the outputs showed：

> Epoch: 9, Test set ELBO: nan, time elapse for current epoch: 2.188002586364746

And then I got an error:

> ParameterError: Audio buffer is not finite everywhere

The dataset used is GTZAN Genre Collection.
python version: 3.8 
tensorflow version: 2.3 
Here is hyperparameters:

```py
train_size = 60000
BATCH_SIZE = 10
test_size = 10000
epochs = 20
latent_dim = 2 
num_examples_to_generate = 10

BASE_PATH = '/kaggle/input/gtzan-genre-collection/genres'
```

Here is my model:

```py
class Resnet1DBlock(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self, kernel_size, filters, type = 'encode'):
        super(Resnet1DBlock, self).__init__()
    
        if type == 'encode':
            self.conv1a = layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, 2, padding = "same")
            self.conv1b = layers.Conv1D(filters, kernel_size, 1, padding = "same")
            self.norm1a = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()
            self.norm1b = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()
        elif type == 'decode':
            self.conv1a = layers.Conv1DTranspose(filters, kernel_size, 1, padding = "same")
            self.conv1b = layers.Conv1DTranspose(filters, kernel_size, 1, padding = "same")
            self.norm1a = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()
            self.norm1b = tfa.layers.InstanceNormalization()
        else:
            return None

    def call(self, input_tensor):
        x = tf.nn.relu(input_tensor)
        x = self.conv1a(x)
        x = self.norm1a(x)
        x = layers.LeakyReLU(0.4)(x)

        x = self.conv1b(x)
        x = self.norm1b(x)
        x = layers.LeakyReLU(0.4)(x)

        x += input_tensor
        return tf.nn.relu(x)

# CNN-VAE
class CVAE(tf.keras.Model):

    def __init__(self, latent_dim):
        super(CVAE, self).__init__()
        self.latent_dim = latent_dim
        self.encoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape = (1, 90001),),

                layers.Conv1D(64, 1, 2),
                Resnet1DBlock(64, 1, 'encode'),
                layers.Conv1D(128, 1, 2),
                Resnet1DBlock(128, 1, 'encode'),
                layers.Conv1D(128, 1, 2),
                Resnet1DBlock(128, 1, 'encode'),
                layers.Conv1D(256, 1, 2),
                Resnet1DBlock(256, 1, 'encode'),

                layers.Flatten(),
                layers.Dense(latent_dim + latent_dim),
            ]
        )
        self.decoder = tf.keras.Sequential(
            [
                tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape = (latent_dim,)),
                layers.Reshape(target_shape = (1, latent_dim)),
                Resnet1DBlock(512, 1, 'decode'),
                layers.Conv1DTranspose(512, 1, 1),
                Resnet1DBlock(256, 1, 'decode'),
                layers.Conv1DTranspose(256, 1, 1),
                Resnet1DBlock(128, 1, 'decode'),
                layers.Conv1DTranspose(128, 1, 1),
                Resnet1DBlock(64, 1, 'decode'),
                layers.Conv1DTranspose(64, 1, 1),
                layers.Conv1DTranspose(90001, 1, 1)
            ]
        )
        
    @tf.function
    def sample(self, eps = None):
        if eps is None:
            eps = tf.random.normal(shape = (200, self.latent_dim))
        return self.decode(eps, apply_sigmoid = True)
    
    @tf.function
    def encode(self, x):
        mean, logvar = tf.split(self.encoder(x), num_or_size_splits = 2, axis = 1)
        return mean, logvar
    
    @tf.function 
    def reparameterize(self, mean, logvar):
        eps = tf.random.normal(shape = mean.shape)
        return eps * tf.exp(logvar * .5) + mean
    
    @tf.function
    def decode(self, z, apply_sigmoid = False):
        logits = self.decoder(z)
        if apply_sigmoid:
            probs = tf.sigmoid(logits)
            return probs
        return logits

optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0003, beta_1 = 0.9, beta_2 = 0.999, epsilon = 1e-08)

@tf.function
def log_normal_pdf(sample, mean, logvar, raxis = 1):
    log2pi = tf.math.log(2. * np.pi)
    return tf.reduce_sum(
         -.5 * ((sample - mean) ** 2. * tf.exp(-logvar) + logvar + log2pi), axis = raxis)
@tf.function
def compute_loss(model, x):
    mean, logvar = model.encode(x)
    z = model.reparameterize(mean, logvar)
    x_logit = model.decode(z)
    cross_ent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = x_logit, labels = x)
    logpx_z = -tf.reduce_sum(cross_ent, axis = [1,2])
    logpz = log_normal_pdf(z, 0., 0.)
    logqz_x = log_normal_pdf(z, mean, logvar)
    return -tf.reduce_mean(logpx_z + logpz - logqz_x)
@tf.function
def train_step(model, x, optimizer):

    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
            mean, logvar = model.encode(x)
            z = model.reparameterize(mean, logvar)
            x_logit = model.decode(z)
            cross_ent = tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits = x_logit, labels = x)
            logpx_z = -tf.reduce_sum(cross_ent, axis = [1,2])
            logpz = log_normal_pdf(z, 0., 0.)
            logqz_x = log_normal_pdf(z, mean, logvar)
            loss_KL = -tf.reduce_mean(logpx_z + logpz - logqz_x)
            reconstruction_loss = tf.reduce_mean(
                     tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(x, x_logit))
            total_loss = reconstruction_loss + loss_KL
    gradients = tape.gradient(total_loss, model.trainable_variables)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, model.trainable_variables))

random_vector_for_generation = tf.random.normal(
    shape = [num_examples_to_generate, latent_dim])

model = CVAE(latent_dim)
```

Can anyone tell me what is the common cause of this problem? What can I do to solve it ? 
Sorry to make you see such a smelly and long code. I'm a total freshman and know nothing, but really really need your help QAQ.